# Compute a Max of two columns in two worksheets E

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have found questions on here relating to finding two distinct max/mins for two distinct column sets, but I'm looking to use this code and instead of have it only check column K, I want it to also check Column K on my second worksheet Sheet2 "Archive".

So if Column K contains 1,2,3 on Sheet1, and Column K contains 8,10,12 on Sheet2, then the MsgBox should read out "13"

```
Sub IncrementMax ()
Dim NewValue as Long

NewValue = Application.Max(Range("K1:K" & Range("K" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)) + 1
MsgBox NewValue

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Max` function allows multiple parameters, so just pass it two Ranges:

```
Sub IncrementMax ()
    Dim NewValue as Long

    NewValue = Application.Max(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K1", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), _
                               Worksheets("Archive").Range("K1", Worksheets("Archive").Range("K" & Worksheets("Archive").Rows.Count).End(xlUp))) + 1
    MsgBox NewValue

End Sub
```